# NodeJS Storing Private Key As String To .txt Is Writing "[object Object]"

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, cryptography, txt

So I am trying to store an ec key pair from the [elliptic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elliptic) library as a string to a .txt file, but it is writing "[object Object]" to the file.

**EDIT:** Below you will see I turned the object into strings twice, this is a separate issue of its own that I fixed.

How I am writing it to the file...

```
        this.keyPair = ec.genKeyPair();

        this.sec = this.keyPair.toString('hex');
        
        fs.writeFileSync(skeyPath, JSON.stringify(this.sec));
```

How I am reading the file (although the "[object,object]" is written to it)...

```
    const rawSkey = fs.readFileSync(skeyPath);
    
    const skey = Buffer.from(rawSkey, 'hex');
```

As you can see, I tried turning the keypair to a hex string to store into skeyPath (named secret.txt) and then retrieving it as a buffer. This unfortunately doesn't work if what's written to the file is what was mentioned.

What am I doing wrong, and are there perhaps better file formats to store array buffer strings to?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably `this.keyPair.toString('hex');` doesn't return a string key
i already checked out the package page on npm [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/elliptic)
and i believe that you have to get the public key and store it and get the private key and store it separately
also i suggest you to use [Crypto](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) that provided by nodejs

Comment: You do have sense with saying I should aim to atleast store the private key rather the entire key pair. Atleast this way i can regenerate the keypair from the private. I will be giving this an update once I get back doing it. Thank you for your response.